# Three dice are rolled three times. What is the probability that the number on the fourth roll will yield a same number as the previous rolls?

Tags: probability

There are three fair 6-sided dice, which can give a result ranging from 3–18. They are rolled three times. What is the probability that the number obtained on the fourth roll is the same as one of the previous three rolls?

Comment: When you say 'same as the previous rolls' do you mean the fourth roll is the same as the *sum* of the previous three? or that it is the same as at least one of the previous rolls (individually).

Comment: @basket: I think that the notion of "$18$" implies that OP means "sum". I have based my answer (below) on this assumption, but it appears that other answers here are assuming otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be the result of the $i$th roll, and let $p_s=P(X_i=s),$ so that $p_3=p_{18}=\frac1{216},$ $p_4=p_{17}=\frac3{216},$ $p_5=p_{16}=\frac6{216},$ $p_6=p_{15}=\frac{10}{216},$ $p_7=p_{14}=\frac{15}{216},$ $p_8=p_{13}=\frac{21}{216},$ $p_9=p_{12}=\frac{25}{216},$ and $p_{10}=p_{11}=\frac{27}{216}.$

The probability you want is
$$P(X_1=X_4\text{ or }X_2=X_4\text{ or }X_3=X_4)$$
$$=1-P(X_1\ne X_4\text{ and }X_2\ne X_4\text{ and }X_3\ne X_4)$$
$$=1-\sum_{s=3}^{18}P(X_4=s\text{ and }X_1\ne s\text{ and }X_2\ne s\text{ and }X_3\ne s)$$

$$=1-\sum_{s=3}^{18}P(X_4=s)P(X_1\ne s)P(X_2\ne s)P(X_3\ne s)$$
$$=1-\sum_{s=3}^{18}p_s(1-p_s)^3$$
$$=\frac{12401}{46656}\text{ if I did the arithmetic right.}$$

Comment: The events $X_4 \neq X_i$ are not independent?

Comment: I think you have give the correct setup of what OP is asking for. Just use inclusion-exclusion principle to attack the union should do it.

Comment: @BGM Is it OK now?

Comment: Ok I just over-read the pre edit version. Nice application of law of total probability and they are independent.

Comment: No, I don't believe $X_1=X_4$ and $X_2=X_4$ are independent events.

Comment: but they are conditionally independent, given $X_4 = s$. So you just make use of a nice technique.